# database physical storage for character type

Tags: sql-server, encoding, storage, character

For SQL Server 2005/2008, after some self-study, I am not sure whether my understanding about how character data type is physically stored is correct. Please help to review and comment. Here is my understanding, please review and feel free to correct me.

- when using unicode character type (e.g. nvarchar), underlying character are stored in UCS-2 encoding (i.e. character is stored physically in the form of related UCS-2 defined bit sequences for the character). Collation defines comparison and sorting, no codepage in this situation;
- when using non-unicode character type (e.g. varchar), underlying character are stored physically as bits defined in related code page defined by collation. So in this case, collation defines not only comparison/sorting, but also which codepage (character, bit value represents the character, and using the same bit value to store the character in database physical storage).

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

I think you are wright ,see the link for further info
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/faq/data-types-p01.aspx

Comment: One of my further confusion is -- character are stored physically the same as related bit sequence defined in UCS-2(when using unicode character data type)/codepage(when using non-unicode character data type), no additional level of conversion (between the physical storage and related bit sequence defined in UCS-2/codepage)?

Comment: BTW: in the referred document, I did not find how character data type bits are physically stored, i.e. whether the same as UCS-2/codepage defined bit sequence or using some other format (which has an additional level of bit sequence conversion).